# Prove that $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ satisfies $f^n (x)=\frac{x}{1+nx}$ (by induction).

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I am quite familiar with induction as it pertains to sequences and series. But I have no idea how to approach this.

> Consider the function $f:[0,∞)→[0,∞)$ given by 
>   $$f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}.$$
>
> Prove, by induction, that for any $n\in\mathbb N$,
>   $$f^n (x)=\frac{x}{1+nx}.$$

Comment: You can begin ... with the base case

Comment: but what does $f^1$ mean in terms of functions?

Comment: $f^1$ would be $f$, and $f^0$ would be the identity function, (I'm not sure which $\mathbb{N}$, you're using, but the statement is true for both. $f^n = f \circ f^{n-1}$

Comment: how does the exponent change the function itself?>

Comment: It's not including 0, so $f^1$ would be my base case. I will start with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the base $n=0$:

$$f^0(x) = id(x) = x = \frac{x}{1}=\frac{x}{1+0x}$$

For the step:

Assume that for some arbitrary $k$ we have $f^k(x) = \frac{x}{1+kx}$

Then:

$$f^{k+1}(x) = f(f^k(x)) = f(\frac{x}{1+kx}) = \frac{\frac{x}{1+kx}}{\frac{x}{1+kx}+1}=\frac{\frac{x}{1+kx}}{\frac{x}{1+kx}+\frac{1+kx}{1+kx}}=\frac{\frac{x}{1+kx}}{\frac{x+1+kx}{1+kx}}=\frac{x}{1+(k+1)x}$$